Could We Create Demons
In my story the supernatural isn’t composed of myths or legends, but is backed up by science and observation. And a main focus is particularly on Demons in my world, which I’ve laid out as a theory about their possible biology. This is all to see if something like this could exist.
The theory is that Demons are a type of airborne bacteria that inhabit underground regions of the earth. What makes them so unique is what they do when they enter into the body of an organism. Once they go into a human or animal body, they’ll cause the host to have symptoms similar to the drug Flakka. The symptoms include hyper agitation, paranoia, elevated heart rate, hallucinations and over twitching of the muscles. They also contain iron particles which makes them attracted to magnetic and electrostatic fields. They also can carry electrical information which a skilled person can use to send thoughts to someone.
This is my theory about my demons in my story and I wanted to hear if anyone thinks something like this is possible, or if someone has a better spin on this idea of mine.

First petition the Oxford Dictionary to change the definition of the word Demon to something we can easily create or that we have already.. ;) // "This is my theory" no, this is your "idea" // how do you expect having information is going to let you send it? those are two very different unrelated things you know, you'll need two separate mechanisms, one for each thing.

Pelinore: I’m just asking if something like this in my story is possible, that’s all

Fair warning: I think your question is likely to be closed, because it's not exactly the kind of question this community wants to be a home for. We don't want people to post "here's my idea, is it good?" because there is no way to consistently answer those questions well, and there's no standard by which to evaluate the answers: one person says it's good, another person says it's not, all you can do is agree to disagree, and that exchange has very little value to posterity.

Tom: ok thank you for the info. I’m new here and now I know what to write

There's a related post (if you substitute aliens with your Demons): Plausable alien telepathy which may interest you. (Note, the [science-based] tag is not present there)

No time to answer but, extrapolate and take from this what you will: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33416798/

Deep earth bacteria-those exist.The symptoms are plausible for an infection. The wireless communications is well into requiring magic. Why would bacteria have genetics for something that is complex, power hungry, and that offers no survival advantage?

you need to better lay out what your end goal is. what do they need to do, "carry electrical signals" is super vague are you looking for biological radio? remote control? magnetoreception?

Out of curiosity, and I just read your other question, but do you even know what actual angels and demons are?

@elemtilas I think we can safely assume he's using the names demons and angels in a similar fashion to in His Dark Materials, more eccentric euphemism than literal.

@Pelinore -- I did not assume anything close to that!

@elemtilas I know you didn't, I was suggesting that we might ;)

@Pelinore --- Well, all the better reason to ask!

No, it could not exist in reality
But that doesn't mean you can't make your demons like that. If the rest of your story is good, people will be fine with your unique explanation for why the world has some ultra-twitchy people walking around doing bad things.

Here are some reasons it couldn't work like this in reality:

The symptoms of a bacterial infection are not up to the bacteria to decide: they are caused by the host's immune reaction and the damage being done by the bacteria to the host -- and that stuff is: sore throats, runny noses, inflammation, fever, etc.
Now, if the bacteria is itself supernatural, then it could do all kinds of things, like make people hallucinate and act like twitchy junkies, but that's not science-based. The definition of "science-based" can be summarized as "not supernatural."

If the bacteria responds to magnetic fields, it will have a hard time surviving outside a host, because it can't go to places where bacteria survives, but must follow magnetic fields wherever they go -- which is not into the open mouths of hapless victims, it's into the sky, where it will be subjected to a bunch of UV radiation and reactive chemicals in the atmosphere and die quickly.
Again, supernatural forces that decide to take the form of bacteria could make this work, because that supernatural force would not have to mindlessly do whatever is dictated by the magnetic fields of the Earth and Sun. It could decide to follow the breeze and then decide to swim into somebody's ear, because it has magic and can control its movement (or the wind). But, again, that would not be science-based.

It's not clear that human or animal bodies can "carry" electrical information in any meaningful sense. Our bodies have lots of charged particles, and we have a substantial amount of electrical wiring, including our brains and nervous systems and muscles. But those electrical channels are in-use by our bodies for essential functions. If your demonic bacteria hijacks the electrical rhythm of a human heart, it might be able to encode some information in that part of the electrical system, but that will stop the heart from doing the job of pumping blood correctly, so the human will die within minutes, and then the electrical system of the heart will go dead, erasing the information with it. So your "skilled individual" had better be handy when a person becomes infected, because they will only have a few minutes before the Etch-a-Sketch in that host gets shaken for the last time.
If your demon is some kind of supernatural entity that has chosen to take the form of bacteria but still has all of its evil magic, then yeah, it can totally use awesome evil magic to smuggle some secret messages inside the electrical system of the host's body. (But that is not science-based.)
Although I gotta admit: I don't see the point: do demons need to store a lot of information outside their own minds? Like, are they taking a lot of notes? Do they need to send letters to somebody? Do they have to fill out paperwork?
I assume you want this because you want your hero to be able to learn important things by doing a ritual on the bodies of the demons they have just killed in combat, like in a video game or anime or lit-RPG, but I gotta warn you that this is extremely lazy.

Real Talk
You want demons to hide messages inside their foot soldiers because it makes your storytelling job easier. But your demons have no reason to actually send information this way, and doing so would make their jobs harder. No demon would do this, even if they could, except as a taunting message to the humans or the hero. No demon would ever put useful information or secrets in a host's body. If you have important secrets, you don't write them down, so that nobody can discover them. The only message your hero is likely to find is "you can't stop me from killing them all one by one".




Don't worry about it being science-based! I think your idea is cool. It could work in a video game like Devil May Cry or Diablo, or in a movie like 28 Days Later or The King's Speech. If the rest of your ideas are cool and fun, nobody is going to worry about the fact that electrical fields don't work that way, or whatever.
You don't need anybody's permission to whip up a cool explanation for monsters. Just do it!

"Do they need to send letters to somebody? Do they have to fill out paperwork?" Hah! Makes me think of The Screwtape Letters.

"The symptoms of a bacterial infection are not up to the bacteria to decide ..." <-  Yes, but inflammation can cause a LOT of different symptoms depending on where it is.  An inflamed gland can cause a surge or scarcity of a given hormone causing personality changes, and inflammation of the nervous system can cause a very wide range of psychological side effects depending on precisely what parts of the nervous system the bacteria decides to attack.

I echo @Nosajimiki, and add that Bacteria can, and often do, produce very specific symptons on the body of their hosts. If your bacteria is able to produce hormone-equivalent chemicals while inside someone's body, they can create all sorts of effects over time.

Dozens of known bacteria directly alter the hosts behavior to their benefit, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/am/pii/S0166223620302150

bacteria cannot both be airborne and contain iron in any significant quantity. There are iron-filled bacteria, but they are so heavy they sink in water, nevermind the air.
Rather, lets consider an alternative:
The Demon bacteria infect human brain through the sinuses. One of the main symptoms the infection causes, is a significant imbalance in eletrolytes and well as in iron build up. This causes the brain to be slowly poisoned with iron buildup and over-conductivity, making the person act as if they were on amphetamines. These symptoms include physical aggression, sexual aggression and excessive desire to touch others, which spreads the bacteria.
At the final stages of the infection, the brain of the victim becomes susceptible to strong magnetic fields (maybe not ambient magnetic field, but things like power-wires or lighting storms). But this point the host is dying anyway,, their brain being slowly filled with rust and brine until they die of a stroke.
However, in the brief time between the moment over-conductivity happened, and the death of the host, it is possible for two hosts to "ping" one another with electromagnetic impulses, as long as they both are within a strong em field. This is simply done by squeezing their jaws, and tensing the mandible muscle, which sends shots of pressurized blood into the bacteria-filled sinus cavities. Skilled hosts can use it as a kind of "Morse code", essentially communicating with headaches.

That’s incredibly helpful thank you so much

Use Bacterial Meningitis as a starting point
Bacterial Meningitis is one of the few bacterial infections that can attack the brain directly.  It checks nearly all of the symptom boxes: hallucinations, hyper agitation and paranoia (is a common response to the severe headaches and confusion), and muscle twitching (because it causes seizures).
For bonus "demonic symptoms", it also makes people extremely sensitive to light  and can make them forget thier own Personally Identify Information (name, location, and date) giving friends and family the impression that the person has been replaced by a stranger.
One of the bacteria strains that can cause Meningitis , L. monocytogenes, is most commonly found in soil, water, and decaying vegetation and can be airborne; so, it fits the pathology pattern as well.
The only thing Meningitis does not allow is psychic communications. That said, different strains of Meningitis can cause different levels of inflammation in different parts of the brain; so, if your setting allows for the possibility of a human to have psychic abilities, then the infection could inflame that part of the brain multiplying the person's natural psychic ability. So, someone who's Psionic Ganglion is normally too under-developed to do anything, might experience a significant inflammation and increased blood flow to that part of the brain leading to noticeable psychic abilities until the infection passes.

I would go with a rabbies variant, that also has memories & a personality encoded into the disease.
If you let him, angry illness will bite all the villagers, the whole world will become deamon runners, with memories of all of the deamons lifetime until the salvia was produced.
Blood magic: The blood contains the strain and causes madness if deamons mix.
Pacts are fullfilled by undiscovered background deamons, who have memories of burried treasure, looted stuff hidden in the past.

considering that it would be biological, not likely, but I see it as something possible if you have your "demons" as something that isn't living.
You said a Demon's symptoms are similar to flakka, well why have it be just that. Have your demons be an aerosolized form of the flakka drug that you can direct using electric or magnetic fields.
although it might end up becoming less of a part of nature, and more of something manmade.
