Creating non supernatural Angels
In my story the supernatural is no longer myth, but part of the natural world. My question is would it be possible for a type of metaphysical creature to exist, or better yet a unique type of bacteria that has similar properties to The Angel’s Glow bacteria “a bacteria that helped to heal soldier’s wounds”. As well as give it a reason for why it being attracted to churches in a scientific sense.

how is this different than the question you have asked earlier? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/257658/30492

Weren't angels traditionally associated with smiting, and scaring the bejeesus (or bemoses, I guess) out of people in order to send a message?

It is different in that they have a different species they want examined. Weird biology evolving is a standard worldbuilding question.

can i have anything I want once magic is involved yes, can I have a non-specific poorly defined thing, who knows.

It seems to me that you're asking for permission to create them for your story - sure, why not.

The bacteria is copper reliant.
Copper is a common material for churches and cathederals in your world, and this bacteria only thrives with large copper deposits. As such, people have traditionally associated it with religion.
If you spend a lot of time with copper materials and get infected, the bacteria will tend to make you glow, and secretes chemicals to kill other bacteria to reduce competition. As such priests and deeply religious people have been seen as descendants of angels.
They have also taken to spreading their blood over blades and stabbing it into people. Heretics and atheists who don't spend a lot of time in churches (or copper) and who don't have immunity to this bacteria will tend to be infected and killed by this bacteria. This is called a holy smite.
